# Rails: Help spot the multiple redirect in this action please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been through a number of similar questions but still can't spot the multiple redirects in my action. Can you help me spot it? Also are there any generic tips for avoiding the so called Double Render Error?

The code is as follows:

```
def st_buy_now_process
  #create user in system
  encrypted = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
  if (User.where("email = ?", params[:email]).exists?)    
    flash[:alert] = 'User exists. Please try again.'    
    redirect_to "/st_buy_now"          
  elsif (User.create(email: params[:email], encrypted_password: encrypted))
    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
        :description => params[:email],
        :card => {
          :number => params[:cc],
          :exp_month => params[:exp_1],
          :exp_year => params[:exp_2],
          :cvc => params[:cvc],
          :name => params[:name]
        },
        :email => params['email']
      })               
      p="#{params['plan']}_#{params['billing-cycle']}"
      subscr = customer.subscriptions.create(:plan => p)
      user = User.where("email = ?", params[:email]).first
      user.payg = ({:cus_id => customer.id, :subscr_id => subscr.id}).to_json
      user.plan = p
      user.save
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e          
      flash[:alert] = 'Please try again'
      redirect_to "/st_buy_now"
    end  
    RestClient.post "https://api:key-nnnn",
      :from => "<test@test.com>",
      :to => "#{params[:email]}",
      :subject => "Welcome to test",
      :text => "\n\n\n#{File.read("app/views/misc/mail_sign_up.txt")}\n\n\n"
    cookies['logged_in'] = {
      :value => '1',
    }
    cookies['us_id'] = {
      :value => params[:email],
    }      
    flash[:notice] = 'Registration successful.' 
    redirect_to :controller => 'misc', :action => 'create_1'
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Please try again'
    redirect_to "/st_buy_now"
  end
end
```

The error message highlights the last but one redirect - the line after the `"Registration successful."` alert.

Comment: Can you please format it properly.

Comment: You have two redirects if you create a `User` and there is a `Stripe::CardError` (in the `elsif` section).

Comment: Agree with @ptd. You should terminate in `rescue` section or change order `begin... end` with 'if...elsif...else` and use `flash[:alert]...` only once.

Answer (score 1):

When you rescue an exception, execution of your code continues on from there as normal, so your `redirect_to "/st_buy_now"` in your `rescue` block plus the `redirect_to :controller => 'misc', :action => 'create_1'` you're getting the error on are your two redirects.

You probably want to throw a `return` in that `rescue` block.

Answer (score 1):

What about this, if customer got created proceed further and redirect and if error occur redirect_to "/st_buy_now"

```
def st_buy_now_process
    #create user in system
    encrypted = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
    if (User.where("email = ?", params[:email]).exists?)    
       flash[:alert] = 'User exists. Please try again.'    
       redirect_to "/st_buy_now"          
    elsif (User.create(email: params[:email], encrypted_password: encrypted))
        begin
          customer = Stripe::Customer.create({:description => params[:email],:card => {:number => params[:cc], :exp_month => params[:exp_1],:exp_year => params[:exp_2], :cvc => params[:cvc], :name => params[:name]},:email => params['email'] })               
          p="#{params['plan']}_#{params['billing-cycle']}"
          subscr = customer.subscriptions.create(:plan => p)
          user = User.where("email = ?", params[:email]).first
          user.payg = ({:cus_id => customer.id, :subscr_id => subscr.id}).to_json
          user.plan = p
          user.save
          RestClient.post "https://api:key-nnnn",
            :from => "<test@test.com>",
            :to => "#{params[:email]}",
            :subject => "Welcome to test",
            :text => "\n\n\n#{File.read("app/views/misc/mail_sign_up.txt")}\n\n\n"
          cookies['logged_in'] = {
            :value => '1',
          }
          cookies['us_id'] = {
            :value => params[:email],
          }      
          flash[:notice] = 'Registration successful.' 
          redirect_to :controller => 'misc', :action => 'create_1'
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e          
          flash[:alert] = 'Please try again'
          redirect_to "/st_buy_now"
        end  
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Please try again'
      redirect_to "/st_buy_now"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite there yet but this helps. When I try the suggested code I keep getting Please try again. It's got me thinking though if I should be leaving a user on the database if the stripe customer is not created due to an error. I wonder what best practice is there, but that's another question.